# autocomplete in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete feature in jquery to show the users list intellisense.

for formatItem, i am using `FirstName + " " + LastName + " [" + EmailAddress + "]";`
for formatResult, i am showing `FirstName + " " + LastName`

I need to get the selected users userid, how can i get in autocomplete feature?

Say, I have a textbox to enter the name of the user with autocomplete functionality. And a button near the textbox to add the entered user's userid to the database. I need to show only the `FirstName + " " + LastName` in textbox and while saving it i need to use userid.

Where can i store the Useridfor the User entered in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's actual code from a current project

```
    $("#venue_name").autocomplete(self._venueAutoCompleteUrl, {
        multiple: false,
        autoFill: true,
        scroll: true,
        parse: function(data) {
            return $.map(eval(data), function(row) {
                return { data: row, value: row.Name, Id: row.Id, result: row.Name }
            });
        },
        formatItem: function(item) {
            return "<strong>" + item.Name + "</strong><br/>" + item.Address;
        },
        formatResult: function(row) { return row.Id; }
    }).result(function(e, item) {
        $("#selected_venue_address").show();
        $("#selected_venue_address").html("<small>" + item.Address + "</small><br/>");
        $("#Event_Venue").val(item.Id);
    });
```

Notice the last part (.result(function(e, item){} )

The last part sets the venue id to the hidden field Event_Venue

Answer (score 0):

you can have a hidden field. When user selects the value you can get User ID and put it into hidden field. On button's click pass the value of hidden field with text box.